# On Mouse Over, my text and image moves on left side in a weird way

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just added a small code to an existing one; to have a Text below an image. Plus On Mouse Over the Text should be highlighted in blue.
The things working for me, but somehow the text and image moves to left side on mouse over. I really don't know why. Can someone help me pls.
The image is in  tag.

```
<td align="right" valign="bottom" id="helpid">
<a href="javascript: void(null)" onClick="if(legendDIV.style.visibility=='visible') { legendDIV.style.visibility='hidden'; isClickonLegend = 1; } else { legendDIV.style.visibility='visible'; isClickonLegend = 1;}">
```

Help

hghlightBG id the JS function i have written to make Text color blue on mouse over.
This is the only modification I have done in existing  tag .

Javascript Code :

```
function highlightBG(id,action) {   
    if(action==0)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).className='AttachOnMouseOverText';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).className='AttachOnMouseOutText';
    }
}
```

CSS Code:

```
.AttachOnMouseOverText{
    color: blue;        
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
}
.AttachOnMouseOutText{
    color: black;       
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;     
}
```

Comment: provide your css also

Comment: This is the code:
<td align="right" valign="bottom" id="helpid">
    <a href="javascript: void(null)" onClick="if(legendDIV.style.visibility=='visible') { legendDIV.style.visibility='hidden'; isClickonLegend = 1; } else { legendDIV.style.visibility='visible'; isClickonLegend = 1;}">
<img src="#ContactsImagePath#qmark_sm.gif" border="0" onMouseOver="highlightBG('helpid',0)" onMouseOut="highlightBG('helpid',1)" alt="Help">
</a>
    <br>Help
  </td>

Comment: @Vasu: better to edit the main question ...

Comment: Javascript :
function highlightBG(id,action) { 
  if(action==0)
  {
         document.getElementById(id).className='AttachOnMouseOverText';
  }
  else
  {
         document.getElementById(id).className='AttachOnMouseOutText';
  }
 }

Comment: you css seems to be fine. i think there is something wrong in your legendDiv html

Comment: legendDiv was already written. The addition was only onMouseOver and onMouseOut in <img> tag. The funny part is - when i remove this onmouse events the text and image looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing at least some of it is because you change the font size.
And another thing, when you use javascript to change style always try to check if you can do it directly with css selectors.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="bottom" id="helpid">
        <a href="javascript: void(null);" onClick="{...}">
        <img src="#ContactsImagePath#qmark_sm.gif" border="0" alt="Help">
        </a>
        <br>Help
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#helpid {
    color: black;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
}
#helpid:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

This way you set a default display and only change one parameter.

Comment: I tried your code Gil, but it doesn't show up blue on mouse over :(

Comment: CSS : 
.helpid {
    color: black;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
 }
   .helpid:hover {
    color: blue;
 }

Comment: HTML :
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="bottom" id="helpid"> 

<img src="#ContactsImagePath#pipe.gif" alt="" border="0" style="">&nbsp;
       
<a href="javascript: void(null)" onClick="if(legendDIV.style.visibility=='visible') { legendDIV.style.visibility='hidden'; isClickonLegend = 1; } else { legendDIV.style.visibility='visible'; isClickonLegend = 1;}">
<img src="#ContactsImagePath#qmark_sm.gif" border="0" alt="Help">
       </a>
       <br><span>Help</span>

Comment: You wrote **.helpid** so the selector will look for a class in that name. Look in my code and see that I used **#helpid** so the selector will find the element by ID name.
Also, the 'a' element can have a style conflict with another css selector, so you can add it as well.
 Change both selectors to this and it will work: **#helpid, #helpid a {...}**
**#helpid:hover, #helpid:hover a {...}**

Comment: You know what -  it worked for me.. Thanks for your great help.